Error when connecting Google Big Query as a Power BI datasource
When I am attempting to connect to Google Big Query in Power BI desktop, I am getting the error below. I have downloaded the ODBC Driver for Google Big Query (3.0 64-bit) but this has not helped.
I am able to access GBQ in Chrome and add my credentials to the Power BI report once it has been published to the service.
ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the error message for key 'DSSslErrorMessage' with message parameters ['unable to get local issuer certificate'] and component ID 110: Message not found in file "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftPowerBIDesktop_2.136.1202.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\bin\ODBC Drivers\Simba Google BigQuery ODBC Driver\en-US\DSMessages.xml"

This could be a problem on the certificate, somehow similar to this case at Microsoft issue about the ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft] [DSI] you can check this if this can also resolve your issue? This has same answer as @AmilaMGunawardana mention about the googleapis.com

This error occurred because your firewall is blocking traffic from 'googleapis.com'. Whitelist this address and it will work fine.
